# pyspark - easier way to extract key and value from log except using regex

Tags: pyspark

I have below csv file which contains 1 column named '_raw'. here is some sample data in the csv file.

```
_raw
2022-11-22 23:31:23,408               customer=customer1 instance=instance1 user=userA page="page1" subpage="subpage1" behavior=behavior1 ct=ctA id=id3
2022-10-24 20:10:23,408               customer=customer2 instance=instance2 user=userB page="page2" subpage="subpage2" behavior=behavior2 ct=ctB id=id2
...
```

i want transform it to below format by using pyspark.

```
_time, customer, instance, user, page, subpage, behavior
2022-11-22 23:31:23,408, customer1, instance1, userA, page1, subpage1, behavior1
2022-10-24 20:10:23,408, customer2, instance2, userB, page2, subpage2, behavior2
...
```

Can any expert help advise how to extract the desired table?

I have tried the solution with regex, but regex is a bit heavy to extract several columns. Is there any other more easier way to achive the expected transformation?

```
df.withColumn("customer", regexp_extract(col('_raw'), 'customer=(\S+)', 1))\
  .withColumn("instance", regexp_extract(col('_raw'), 'instance=(\S+)', 1 )\
  .withColumn(...)\
  ...
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Regex should do the trick

Comment: Yes. Regex can work. but it's a bit complicated. is there any other easier way to achieve what the expected transformation?